# How does it not know what AppDelegate is?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I am trying to create a swift based framework for iOS. I have one swift file, which I want to embed in my Framework. When I drag and drop into framework folder I get

> "Use of undeclared type 'AppDelegate'"

error?
 [image: Here is the picture]

[image: This is how my directory listed out]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Framework doesn't have an AppDelegate. Instead, use `UIApplicationDelegate` or pass the `AppDelegate` to your class.

**Swift 3.0**

`var appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate`

Comment: Then, how would I get the "appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate"

Comment: @user2884707bond do `appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! UIApplicationDelegate`, unless you have custom properties you're accessing in `AppDelegate` only, in which case you need to come up with another way of accessing those (since everybody's iOS project for this framework might have different custom properties).

Comment: I need another help. I Use FBSDKCoreKit inside my framework. Can I build it without having that framework and Make user import from Facbook SDK for iOS?

Comment: have you found the solution i having the same issue @brimstone
i have custom properties how can access that one from appdelegate class in my framework.